# Customers belong to a specific group can not place order due to Invalid VAT ID error

Tags: magento-1.9, validation, vat

The Invalid VAT ID error does not let the wholesale group customer place order in my wholesale store view. I have disabled Automatic Group Change Based on VAT ID and set the Default Value for Disable Automatic Group Changes Based on VAT ID. I have following questions:

1) To Enable and Configure VAT ID Validation when I go to System > Configuration and Set Current Configuration Scope to wholesale store view, in "Create New Account Options", I set the Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group to “Yes.” How about other fields like "Default Group"? does it matter it be General or wholesale?

2) In step 4 of [this link](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/content/tax/vat-validation-setup.html) says when Current Configuration Scope is set to the applicable store view, "Validate VAT Number button" is seen in Store Information section. However, in my case this button is visible when current store view is set to “Default Config! Should I make some configuration changes to have this button on my wholesale store view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in [the documentation](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/vat-validation.html?Highlight=vat-validation). Due to using the external payment gateway, the validation could not be applied.