# Changing default limiter select options

Tags: magento-1.9, category, grid-layout, collection-limit

By default the limiter's select options are 5 10 15 25. How I can change them to like 3 9 15 24 for all categories.

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend.
You will see there 2 fields for paginating.
One for grid view and one for list view.
Change those values to whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marius. I have asked another question here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82733/customers-belong-to-a-specific-group-can-not-place-order-due-to-invalid-vat-id-e. I appreciate if you take a look at it and hopefully give me some clue

Comment: By the way, can we make different select options in search result page?

Comment: the pagination is global and depends only on the display mode. You can make a different select on the search pages but it requires a lot of code.